# Why am I receiving a Stripe 400 Error - Cannot Use Stripe Token More Than Once?

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments

I am unsure as to why I am receiving the error. I create a token upon job submission and post it to the database for the associated customer. Upon completion of the job, I use the token from the database to complete the transaction. Below is my code for the transaction process.

```
if(isset($_GET["job"])){
        $status = $_GET["status"];
        if($_GET["status"] == 1){

            $jobq = 'SELECT * from jobsubmission WHERE ID='.$_GET["job"];
            $jobres = mysqli_query($conn, $jobq);
            $data = mysqli_fetch_object($jobres);

            $token = $data->stripetoken;
            $bookdetail = 'SELECT driver from booking WHERE job='.$_GET["job"];
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, $bookdetail);
            $data1 = mysqli_fetch_object($res);
            $driver = $data1->driver;
            $driverdetail = 'SELECT stripe_account from driverinformation WHERE ID='.$driver;
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, $driverdetail);
            $data2 = mysqli_fetch_object($res);
            $accountid = $data2->stripe_account;
            $amount = $data->jobpay*100;

            require_once('Stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
            Stripe::setApiKey($key);

            $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
              "amount" => $amount,
              "currency" => "usd",
              "card" => $token,
              "description" => "Charge for the booked job in Swift job"
            ), array('stripe_account' => $accountid));

            if($charge->status == "succeeded"){

                $transid = $charge->id;
                $jobid = $_POST["job"];
                $conn = dbconnection();
                $updqry = 'UPDATE booking set paid=1, paiddate='.time().', transactionid="'.$transid.'" WHERE job='.$jobid;
                $update = mysqli_query($conn, $updqry);
```

Comment: Tokens are only valid for 5 minutes, you'd want to save the token to a Stripe Customer and then charge the customer

Comment: Yeah you want to create a customer object, and then you can save the customer token and charge that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The Stripe charge ID is meant to capture charges immediately (up to 5 minutes from when it was created). If you want to capture the charge later, then you should attach the charge ID to a `Customer` object (which is [shown here](https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-save-a-card-and-charge-it-later)).